# Subconsultas sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Hay que saber el nombre de los alumnos cuya nota media de programación de segundo curso es superior a la de programación

**Aquí adjunto mi consulta:**

```
select nombre
from alumno innner join matricula on (alumno.#a=matricula.#a)
where (select avg(nota)
       from matricula inner join asignatura on (matricula.#asig=asignatura.#asig)
       where (nombre like 'bd') and (nota >(select avg(nota)
                                           from matricula inner join asignatura on (matricula.#asig=asignatura.#asig)
                                            where (nombre like 'programación'));
```

Estructura de la base de datos:

```
create table alumno(
  a smallint not null constraint PK_Alumno primary key,
  nombre varchar (50) not null
  );

create table profesor (
    p smallint not null constraint PK_Prof primary key,
    nombre varchar (50) not null);

create table asignatura (
     asig smallint not null constraint PK_ASIG primary key,
     nombre varchar (50) not null);

create table matrícula (
 asig smallint not null,
 a smallint not null,
  nota numeric (2,0) not null
  constraint Pk_MATR primary key (asig),
  constraint FK_MATR_AL foreign key (a) references alumno (a) on update cascade on delete cascade,
  constraint FK_MATR_AS foreign key (asig) references asignatura (asig) on update cascade on delete cascade);

  create table imparte(
    p smallint not null,
    asig smallint not null,
    curso varchar (30) not null,
    constraint PK_impart primary key (p,asig),
    constraint FK_IMPARTE_P foreign key (p) references profesor (p) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint FK_IMPARTE_ASIG foreign key (asig) references asignatura (asig) on update cascade on delete cascade);
```

Comment: un tip: usa http://sqlfiddle.com/ para armar tu esquema de datos y con toda seguridad en SO te darán muchas ideas para que resuelvas tu problema. Una vez tengas el esquema, actualiza tu pregunta y compartes el link.

Comment: Me da error así que dejo las tablas por aquí:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal lo que tratarías de hacer es:

```
SELECT alumno.nombre
FROM alumno
INNER JOIN matrícula ma ON ma.a=alumno.a
INNER JOIN asignatura aa ON aa.asig= ma.asig
WHERE aa.nombre = 'programación'
GROUP BY alumno.nombre, ma.asig
HAVING avg(ma.nota) > 
        (SELECT avg(mg.nota) FROM matrícula mg WHERE mg.asig = ma.asig)
```

Aunque viendo la definición de tus tablas entiendo que deberías cambiar la Primary Key de la tabla matrícula para que la clave principal esté compuesta por los campos "asig" y "a", y no sólo por asig.

Comment: se me había pasado